# How to bypass zone.js in Angular 2 when using external script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, protractor, zonejs

I have an Angular 1 application with ngUpgrade. The application pulls in an external script file (a 3rd party service's lib), that polls a server via setTimeout..

Now, the application works perfectly, except if I want to test it with Protractor, it is not able to do that, since:

> ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not
>   received in 30 seconds

Is there a way to tell Angular 2 to run the contents of a script tag outside of angulars context?

Answer (score -1):

Try to increase the `allScriptsTimeout: timeout_in_millis` as stated in the [Protractor Timeouts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) page, under the Timeouts from WebDriver section.